# Getting body tag string value in iFrame using javaScript only

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, gwt, ckeditor

**Hello Everyone i am new to javascript and currently facing an issue in getting values of multiple `<p>` tags from a particular iFrame**

[This iFrame is inside HTML tag and i need to get string values inside this iFrame->body.]

Can anyone suggest me any approach to get values ?

> For Every new line it add `<p></p>`
>   Currently am using :
>       `NodeList elementsTextArea = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("iframe");

com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element element = elementsTextArea.getItem(3);`

I do not know what to do forward to get values inside iFrame -> body

Image is here tags : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKwtU.png